# Flutter local notifications daily scheduled notification

Tags: flutter, flutter-local-notification

I've been trying to get Flutter local notifications to work since a week but can't get it to work.
Basically the issue is whenever i create a daily notification, it works only for the first time and then it doesn't show notifications every next day.
Suppose if i set daily scheduled notification at 12:20 PM, it will show notification at 12:20 PM for first time, then the next day it won't show. And when i see the list of pending notifications i can see the notification still present.

here's all my notification code

```dart
class NotificationService {
  // Singleton pattern
  static final NotificationService _notificationService =
      NotificationService._internal();
  factory NotificationService() {
    return _notificationService;
  }

  NotificationService._internal();

  static const channelId = "1";

  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  static const AndroidNotificationDetails _androidNotificationDetails =
      AndroidNotificationDetails(
    channelId,
    "thecodexhub",
    channelDescription:
        "This channel is responsible for all the local notifications",
    playSound: true,
    priority: Priority.high,
    importance: Importance.high,
  );

  static const IOSNotificationDetails _iOSNotificationDetails =
      IOSNotificationDetails();

  final NotificationDetails notificationDetails = const NotificationDetails(
    android: _androidNotificationDetails,
    iOS: _iOSNotificationDetails,
  );

  Future<void> init() async {
    const AndroidInitializationSettings androidInitializationSettings =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');

    const IOSInitializationSettings iOSInitializationSettings =
        IOSInitializationSettings(
      defaultPresentAlert: false,
      defaultPresentBadge: false,
      defaultPresentSound: false,
    );

    const InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(
      android: androidInitializationSettings,
      iOS: iOSInitializationSettings,
    );

    // *** Initialize timezone here ***
    tz.initializeTimeZones();

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      initializationSettings,
      onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification,
    );
  }

  Future<void> requestIOSPermissions() async {
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            IOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.requestPermissions(
          alert: true,
          badge: true,
          sound: true,
        );
  }

  Future<void> showNotification(
      int id, String title, String body, String payload) async {
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      id,
      title,
      body,
      notificationDetails,
      payload: payload,
    );
  }

  Future<void> scheduleNotification(int id, String title, String body,
      DateTime eventDate, TimeOfDay eventTime, String payload,
      [DateTimeComponents? dateTimeComponents]) async {
    final scheduledTime = eventDate.add(Duration(
      hours: eventTime.hour,
      minutes: eventTime.minute,
    ));
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
      id,
      title,
      body,
      tz.TZDateTime.from(scheduledTime, tz.local),
      notificationDetails,
      uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
          UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
      androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
      payload: payload,
      matchDateTimeComponents: dateTimeComponents,
    );
  }

  Future<void> cancelNotification(int id) async {
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancel(id);
  }

  Future<void> cancelAllNotifications() async {
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancelAll();
  }

  Future getNotifications() async {
    final List<PendingNotificationRequest> pendingNotificationRequests =
        await FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin().pendingNotificationRequests();
    return pendingNotificationRequests;
  }
}

Future<void> onSelectNotification(String? payload) async {
  // await navigatorKey.currentState
  //     ?.push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => DetailsPage(payload: payload)));
}
```

and here's how i'm calling it.

```dart
 await notificationService.scheduleNotification(
      1,
      _textEditingController.text,
      "Reminder for your scheduled event at ${eventTime!.format(context)}",
      eventDate!,
      eventTime!,
      jsonEncode({
        "title": _textEditingController.text,
        "eventDate": DateFormat("EEEE, d MMM y").format(eventDate!),
        "eventTime": eventTime!.format(context),
      }),
      getDateTimeComponents(),
    );
  }
```

here is getDateTimeComponents if it matters

```dart
  DateTimeComponents? getDateTimeComponents() {
    if (segmentedControlGroupValue == 1) {
      return DateTimeComponents.time;
    } else if (segmentedControlGroupValue == 2) {
      return DateTimeComponents.dayOfWeekAndTime;
    }
  }
```

it's been week since i'm trying to fix this issue.
Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_local_notifications/latest/flutter_local_notifications/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin/showDailyAtTime.html) it says

> Use zonedSchedule instead by passing a date **in the future** with the
> same time and pass DateTimeComponents.matchTime as the value of the
> matchDateTimeComponents parameter.

You seem to use `DateTimeComponents.time` correctly but I guess your date is not in the future. Can you try adding like a thousand years to your date and see? Maybe because after the first firing, the date is now in the past and it will not fire on the next day because of it.

Comment: Hm.. One thing i want to mention is that this all code is actually from a github repo, and in that app the notifications are working fine, i receive them daily at correct time.
But here in my app, it doesn't seem to work.
So if date was the issue, it'd be there as well right?
here's the github for reference
https://github.com/thecodexhub/flutter-local-notifications-example
Thanks for replying.

Comment: If you yourself tried that repo and it works, my guess would be maybe you are using a different version in your pubspec.yaml (actually should check pubspec.lock to be sure).

Comment: yes, the versions indeed are different.
github version ^9.1.2
my version ^9.6.1
could this cause issue?
The main problem is i have to wait one whole day just to test every time..

Comment: 9.6.1 seems to have a related change here: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications/changelog 

however, what's in pubspec.lock is the actual version being used. I think this is a good chance. I would swap the versions in both projects and see if the working one stops working and non-working one starts working.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I'll downgrade my version to 9.1.2 and see if it works.
Will update then. Thanks again

Comment: sadly it still doesn't work.
Used same version as in the repo.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for answer, here is the solution.

Main

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await initNotifications();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

Future<void> initNotifications() async {
  NotificationService notificationService = NotificationService();
  await notificationService.init();
  if (Platform.isIOS) {
    await notificationService.requestIOSPermissions();
  } else {
    await notificationService.requestAndroidPermission();
  }
}
```

Notifications

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:flutter_timezone/flutter_timezone.dart';
import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tz;
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void backgroundNotificationHandler(NotificationResponse? details) async {}

Future<void> onNotificationTapped(NotificationResponse? payload) async {
}

class NotificationService {
  static final NotificationService _notificationService =
      NotificationService._internal();
  factory NotificationService() {
    return _notificationService;
  }

  Future<NotificationResponse?> getInitialNotification() async {
    final launchDetails =
        await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.getNotificationAppLaunchDetails();
    if (launchDetails?.didNotificationLaunchApp ?? false) {
      return NotificationResponse(
          notificationResponseType:
              NotificationResponseType.selectedNotification,
          payload: launchDetails!.notificationResponse!.payload);
    }
    return null;
  }

  NotificationService._internal();

  static const channelId = "1";

  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  static const AndroidNotificationDetails _androidNotificationDetails =
      AndroidNotificationDetails(
    channelId,
    "randomString",
    channelDescription:
        "This channel is responsible for all the local notifications",
    playSound: true,
    priority: Priority.high,
    importance: Importance.high,
  );

  static const DarwinNotificationDetails _darwinNotificationDetails =
      DarwinNotificationDetails();

  final NotificationDetails notificationDetails = const NotificationDetails(
    android: _androidNotificationDetails,
    iOS: _darwinNotificationDetails,
  );

  void onDidReceiveLocalNotification(
      int id, String? title, String? body, String? payload) async {
    showDialog(
      context: dialogKey.currentContext!,
      builder: (BuildContext context) => CupertinoAlertDialog(
        title: Text(title ?? ''),
        content: Text(body ?? ''),
        actions: [
          CupertinoDialogAction(
            isDefaultAction: true,
            child: const Text('Ok'),
            onPressed: () async {
              Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> init() async {
    const AndroidInitializationSettings androidInitializationSettings =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');

    final DarwinInitializationSettings initializationSettingsDarwin =
        DarwinInitializationSettings(
            onDidReceiveLocalNotification: onDidReceiveLocalNotification);

    final InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(
      android: androidInitializationSettings,
      iOS: initializationSettingsDarwin,
    );

    // *** Initialize timezone here ***
    tz.initializeTimeZones();
    final String currentTimeZone = await FlutterTimezone.getLocalTimezone();
    tz.setLocalLocation(tz.getLocation(currentTimeZone));

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      initializationSettings,
      onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse: backgroundNotificationHandler,
      onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: onNotificationTapped,
    );
  }

  Future<void> requestAndroidPermission() async {
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()!
        .requestPermission();
  }

  Future<void> requestIOSPermissions() async {
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            IOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.requestPermissions(
          alert: true,
          badge: true,
          sound: true,
        );
  }

  Future<void> showNotification(
      int id, String title, String body, String payload) async {
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      id,
      title,
      body,
      notificationDetails,
      payload: payload,
    );
  }

  Future<void> scheduleNotification(
      int id,
      String title,
      String body,
      DateTime eventDate,
      TimeOfDay eventTime,
      String payload,
      String time,
      int? hours,
      [DateTimeComponents? dateTimeComponents]) async {
    eventDate = DateTime(eventDate.year, eventDate.month, eventDate.day);

    final scheduledTime = eventDate.add(Duration(
      hours: eventTime.hour,
      minutes: eventTime.minute,
    ));

    tz.TZDateTime nextInstanceOfTenAM() {
      final tz.TZDateTime now = tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local);
      tz.TZDateTime scheduledDate = tz.TZDateTime.from(scheduledTime, tz.local);

      if (time == 'daily') {
        if (scheduledDate.isBefore(now)) {
          scheduledDate = scheduledDate.add(const Duration(days: 1));
        }
      } else if (time == 'hourly') {
        if (scheduledDate.isBefore(now)) {
          scheduledDate = scheduledDate.add(Duration(hours: hours!));
        }
      }
      return scheduledDate;
    }

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
      id,
      title,
      body,
      nextInstanceOfTenAM(),
      notificationDetails,
      uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
          UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
      androidScheduleMode: AndroidScheduleMode.exactAllowWhileIdle,
      payload: payload,
      matchDateTimeComponents: dateTimeComponents,
    );
  }

  Future<void> cancelNotification(int id) async {
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancel(id);
  }

  Future<void> cancelAllNotifications() async {
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancelAll();
  }

  Future<List<PendingNotificationRequest>> getNotifications() async {
    final List<PendingNotificationRequest> pendingNotificationRequests =
        await FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin().pendingNotificationRequests();
    return pendingNotificationRequests;
  }
}
```