# What's the best way to send a random notification in Flutter at the same time everyday?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to build an app that sends notifications every hour from 9am to 5 pm every day using Flutter. The notification body is randomly chosen from an array. I tried using `flutter_local_notifications`, specifically `zonedSchedule` function, like this:

```
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
      i,
      "Promise",
      uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
          UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
      NotificationRepo.getNotification(notification.category),
      t,
      notificationDetails,
      androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
      matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.time);
```

`NotificationRepo.getNotification(notification.category)` is the function to choose the notification body. The problem is, it's supposed to repeat every day so the notifications get repeated rather than being randomly chosen. Also `flutter_local_notifications` has a limit of 64 scheduled notifications according to the documentation, so I can't schedule them for weeks in advance.
I don't want to use Firebase Messaging because I want the notifications to send offline.
How can I approach this problem?

Comment: Maybe this'll help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73133759/flutter-local-notifications-daily-scheduled-notification

Comment: Thanks! But I mentioned in the question that the problem with zonedSchedule is that the body of the notification gets repeated, but I want it to be randomly chosen every time.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a function that would generate notification messages for example :

```
String notificationMessages() {
List<Strind> messages = ['msg1', 'msg2', 'msg3'];

RandomMessage randomMsg = RandomMessage();

int index = randomMsg.nextInt(messages.length);
return messages[index];
}
```

After that create a function that would schedule the notification according to the time you want :

```
void ScheduleNotification() {
const int start = 9;
const int end = 17;

Timer.periodic(Duration(hour: 2), (timer) async {
DateTime present = DateTime();

int hour = present.hour;

if (hour >= startHour && hour <= endHour) {
  String Noti_message = notificationMessages();

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      0, 'yes', Noti_message, platformChannelSpecifies);
  }
});
}
```

you should also setup the notification settings such as the channel :

```
const NotificationProperties platformChannelSpecifies= NotificationProperties (android : androidplatformChannelSpecifies);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please format the code better

Comment: is the code not understandable?